# Method of Multiple Assignment in Python

Tags: python, syntax, variable-assignment

I'm trying to prepare for a future in computer science, so I started with ECMAScript and I am now trying to learn more about Python. Coming from ECMAScript, seeing multiple assignments such as `a, b, c = 1, 2, 3` leaves me bewildered for a moment, until I realize that there are multiple assignments going on. To make things a bit clearer, I'd really like to do `(a, b, c) = (1, 2, 3)` but I am not sure if this will be a measurable performance hit. From what I understand, tuples are essentially how multiple assignments work regardless, but there are a great many oddities in the world, so I try not to assume anything.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here's a hint for your future in computer science (I've been in the business for 30+ years).  Don't spend time on this kind of optimization question until you can **prove** that the multiple assignment statement is absolutely killing your program.  Until you have **proof** that something's unacceptably slow, use it.  Use everything without worrying about the performance.  Folks who invented the language already worried about that for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should not have any effect on performance. The parenthesis do not make it a tuple, the comma's do. So (1,2,3) is exactly the same as 1,2,3

Comment: Ah... I didn't even think of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

It's extremely easy to check, with the [`dis`](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html?highlight=dis#module-dis) module:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(compile('a,b,c=1,2,3','','exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               4 ((1, 2, 3))
              3 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          3
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
              9 STORE_NAME               1 (b)
             12 STORE_NAME               2 (c)
             15 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(compile('(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)','','exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               4 ((1, 2, 3))
              3 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          3
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
              9 STORE_NAME               1 (b)
             12 STORE_NAME               2 (c)
             15 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE        
>>>
```

See?  Those totally redundant parentheses make absolutely **no** difference to the bytecode that's generated and executed -- just like, say, `a+b` and `(a+b)` will generate and execute exactly the same bytecode as each other.  So, if you like to add redundant parentheses, knock yourself out -- people reading your code may not like them, but ones who are just executing it will never even notice.  Only, why stop at just two pairs of redundant parentheses?  See,

```
>>> dis.dis(compile('(((a,b,c)))=(((1,2,3)))','','exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               4 ((1, 2, 3))
              3 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          3
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
              9 STORE_NAME               1 (b)
             12 STORE_NAME               2 (c)
             15 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE        
>>>
```

six pairs of redundant parentheses (or any number, really) still produce exactly the same code.  Once you leave the obvious minimum number of redundant parentheses (none at all: they're redundant, after all;-), exactly *where* do you stop?-)  And why there, when it's "free" to add yet one more pair... or two... or three...?-)

Answer (score 2):

It also works for lists:

```
a, b, c = [1, 2, 3]
```

works just as well

Comment: And its called 'unpacking' in python

Answer (score 1):

Multiple assignment is implemented as a combination of tuple packing and tuple unpacking, to my knowledge, so it should have the same effect.